# window.onload delay

Tags: javascript, window, onload, delay

i am trying to appendChild() on an existing form, and its not working.
i wonder if i need to delay the page, at least i thought i read that somewhere.
what i am thinking is dynamically altering window onload to be a delay.
do i grab the body tag like any other DOM element?

Comment: Without seeing any code its difficult to know what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Code to execute when DOM is loaded
}, false);
```

Steve

Comment: newbie js question...when programming js, you must rely on memory about attributes and functions, there is not a tool that gives code assist?

Comment: Of course, memory helps (as it always does), but there are plenty of reference libraries out there. I particularly recommend the Mozilla Developer Centre (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript). W3Schools is also good (http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: are there any IDEs that are integrated, to get code assist like help?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try searching StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide+javascript might be of help), and if you don't find anything, perhaps start an new question.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a timeout to delay the call to your method that does the appendChild()...

```
setTimeout(functionName, 200)
```

If you are using jQuery you can use the ready method to delay your code until the page is fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    appendChild();
});
```

Edit: Removed quotes around function call in setTimeout per Steve's suggestion in the comments

Comment: Don't quote the function in "setTimeout", as this calls "eval()". Rather, provide a function reference: "setTimeout(functionName, 200);".

Comment: don't answer with jQuery unless the asker says to. just because a library makes it easier does not mean they are using it.

Comment: @Steve can you provide a reference for your statement? I have not come accross that before.

Comment: @George IV I provided an adequete sample in the first part of my answer to address the question. However, I do not see the harm in showing an additional jQuery sample, especially when using the jQuery solution is better than guessing how long the timeout needs to be.

Comment: @Jimmie R. Houts: See http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Syntax.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the links, while searching for more info on this, I came accross this page which does a good job of explaining it: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2

Comment: @Jimmie R. Houts: That's a great page you found! I've added it to my bookmarks!

Comment: @Jimmie R. Houts: You also need to remove the parentheses. Now, instead of passing code to be executed (as you did when quoting it), you're passing a "function reference" (i.e. you're passing a variable that refers to a function).

Comment: @Steve my bad, didn't mean to leave those on there

Answer (score 0):

the body-element is referenced directly under document,

document.body

But your question is very fuzzy.

If you call your DOM-manipulation from the onload-event, the DOM should be completely loaded. Therefor I assume a delay isn't the way to go.